# ADFS 3.0 works with WS-Federation but fails with SAML

Tags: saml, adfs3.0

We use ADFS 3.0 (Windows 2012 R2) server to access an ASP.NET browser (.NET 4.5) application, which uses ClaimsPrincipal class (part of the Windows Identity Foundation library). The ADFS servers authenticates to our Active Directory. The ASP.NET application runs properly if we use WS-Federation sign-in protocol but fails if we use SAML sign-in protocol. The error message is not helpful "An error occurred"

The ASP.NET is a web form application, developed using VB.NET

My questions:
1) Does ADFS 3.0 with SAML sign in protocol work with ASP.NET web form application which uses ClaimsPrincipal class, which is part of the Windows Identity Foundation libraries?
2) What are the changes (as compared to WS-Federation) we must make to web config in the ASP.NET application, to us SAML sign in protocol?

Thank you.
Chong Chin

Answer (score 1):

To get WS-Fed to work, you either will be using WIF or the WS-Fed NuGet OWIN package?

There is no Microsoft equivalent for SAML.

You need a [SAML stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43) (in the same way that WIF provides a WS-Fed stack).

Comment: Thank you. I went to your link, which showed quite a number of options. Please let me know if you know which one works well for an ASP.NET web forms client. Thank you.

Comment: If you want SAML, look under the C# section. There are two commercial - ComponentSpace and Rock Solid Knowledge - and one free - Sustainsys.

Comment: Thank you for your response